# Who is the Community? Or, how can community earn badges?

Tags: discussion, badges, community-user

Sometimes I see a post being edited by community, or brought to the active page by community. I have seen this post [What does it mean if an edit is attributed to Community?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4510/what-does-it-mean-if-an-edit-is-attributed-to-community), but still if this is exactly the case, how has the user [community](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) earned those two badges? I mean the ones in Arena 51.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a site called Area51, it's pretty easy for Community to become sentient. It probably got bored of bumping stuff and decided to earn some badges.

Seriously though, the code for A51 is supposed to have branched off from the main codebase years ago, so there will be many such differences.

Comment: I just can't wait until we can get it automatically fixing typos. ;-)

Comment: @CodyGray http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/63550/peter-mortensen